# Should I check for database changes?

Tags: database, asynchronous

Is it a good practice to check for database changes to have took place, or is it just a statistically irrelevant overkill?

Ex: user updates some data. JavaScript sends the new data to the server and displays that changes have took place in the callback. Should the server check that the updated record (or node or whatever) has in fact the updated value (selecting it and comparing it with the POST data), or is this just a waste of resources?

Comment: What specific problem are you concerned about?  That your database just doesn't work?  That a two racing POSTs caused your write to be lost?  That your application is not actually using the DB correctly?  That the update was actually committed to the DB and not stuck in your ORM cache waiting to be committed?  Framing the question around your specific concern might yield better advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you're asking if your code should *confirm* that a database update actually happened.

1. Client writes data to database.
2. Updated data gets sent back to the client.
3. Double checking that the operation was successful by comparing the POST and the data in the database.

You don't need to do step 3. It's redundant and as you are guessing, it's more work for the server and database.

Once you write the code and test it, you can trust it's ok. No need to double check.